# Selecting two divs to apply plugin to

Tags: jquery

I want to apply same plugin to two elements in appended div

```
<div class="main">
<div class="profile"><a href="#">John</a></div>
<div class="msg">aaaaaa</div>
<div class="comment">
<div class="profilec"><a href="#">Jane</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have pre-pended the above section on click of a button

Now how can i do this

```
$("#main").prepend(html);

var first= $("#main .main:first").find('.profile').find('a');
var second=$("#main .main:first").find('.comment').find('.profilec').find('a');

$(first,second).myPlugin();
```

I tried this but it isnt working

Comment: is there `#main` in your DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modified form of your code, Please see [here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for the valid selectors

```
$("#main").prepend(html);

var first= $("#main .main:first").find('.profile').find('a');
var second=$("#main .main:first").find('.comment').find('.profilec').find('a');

first.myPlugin();
second.myPlugin();
```

OR

```
$(".main .profile a").add($(".main .profile a")).myPlugin();
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't using just the selectors work?

```
$(".main .profile a, .main .comment .profilec a").myPlugin()
```

You might not need the `find()` at all...

Or, if this is all markup inside `.main`, just using

```
$(".main a").myPlugin()
```

would do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$(selector, context)` which simply fails here, you can pass an array of elements to jQuery:

```
$( [first, second] ).myPlugin();
```

Or use `.add()` method:

```
first.add(second).myPlugin();
```

And I would do:

```
$('#main .main:first a').bar();
```

Or maybe:

```
$(html).appendTo('#main').find('a').foo();
```